# Bullet is colliding with triggers

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

So I have made the bullet but it keeps colliding with the triggers of the map

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
   Enemy_Health enemy =  collision.GetComponent<Enemy_Health>();
    if(enemy != null )
    {
        enemy.TakeDmg(damage);
    }
    Destroy(gameObject);

}
```

Comment: You could give your enemies a tag and check for the tag in the `OnTriggerEnter2D` method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get some colliders to ignore triggers in unity 3D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55250174/how-do-i-get-some-colliders-to-ignore-triggers-in-unity-3d)

Comment: Don't destroy the object unless it hits an enemy?